# MeCab: “ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.”

Tags: python, mecab

This is the first time I use python...

I use win 10 + py38. I used "pip mecab-python3" and successfully installed mecab-python3-1.0.1,but there is something wrong.

And the question as bellow:

```
import MeCab
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-022fc4ee216d> in <module>
----> 1 import MeCab

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\MeCab\__init__.py in <module>
      8 
      9 from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
---> 10 from . import _MeCab
     11 
     12 import os

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _MeCab: The specified module could not be found.
```

How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQxsi.png)

First，download Visual C++ redistributable.